# SQL Selecting average of just two rows

Tags: mysql, rows, average

I am currently just finishing up an SQL Database project for school.

I have used W3school, Google and read over several of the SQL average questions

I want to write a select statement that will allow me to work out the average grade for each programme which is identified here by Pro_id. I know that you can use

`SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name` for the average of the column. I want to get the average of specific rows within the Column

```
SELECT GPA from enroll
WHERE Pro_id='4010'
```

I thought the above would work but got :

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'GPA' in 'field list'

```
+------------+--------+--------+------+-------+
| Student_id | Mod_id | Pro_id | GPA  | Grade |
+------------+--------+--------+------+-------+
| 04655236   | 111111 | 4010   | 4.84 | A+    |
| 04655236   | 22222  | 4010   | 3.23 | B-    |
| 05655236   | 22222  | 4010   | 3.84 | A-    |
| 06655236   | 33333  | 4011   | 2.84 | B-    |
| 07655236   | 44444  | 4011   | 2.23 | C-    |
| 08655236   | 55555  | 4012   | 2.23 | C-    |
+------------+--------+--------+------+-------+
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to enclose it in a "tick" .. The character above your TAB Key

Answer (score 0):

Your table definition may not be correct as the data you've provided works fine in the demos:

```
SELECT AVG(GPA)
FROM enroll
WHERE Pro_id = 4010
GROUP BY Pro_id
```

**Result**

```
| AVG(GPA) |
------------
|        4 |
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/584fc/1)

For all programmers:

```
SELECT Pro_id, AVG(GPA)
FROM enroll
GROUP BY Pro_id
```

**Result**

```
| PRO_ID | AVG(GPA) |
---------------------
|   4010 |        4 |
|   4011 |      2.5 |
|   4012 |        2 |
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/584fc/2)

Comment: Thank you I had made a syntax error. You helped me point it out sorry to have wasted your time but you saved a LOT of mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `GPA` from `enroll`
WHERE `Pro_id` = '4010'
```